# In IOS Objective C, how to have an automatic size cell the content size of its child UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I am working with ios, programming the interface of an iPhone app with the Storyboard and auto layout.

I have a tableview (tableview level1), with custom tableview cells. I have those tableview cells to have other table views (tableview level2) inside of them. And I want the tableview cells to get the heigh of their child tableview.

Is it possible?

[Schema of what I want to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpGfQ.png)

Comment: rather make a sectioned tableView and set your label as section header, u will get the required UI

Comment: Thank you @SandeepBhandari!

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to not implement a tableview inside another because of iOS recommendations.